# Integrate paypal from my iPhone app

Tags: iphone, paypal

i want to integrate paypal in my app...

but worried about that will apple accept my app.

i have hear that apple allow only inAppPurchase ....

Has anyone successes with his app integrated with Paypal ..

help please.......and please also provide any tutorial for it(if possible)...

Comment: Read the contract you agreed with when you became an Apple developer. That will tell you what you are allowed to do regarding in-app purchases. It is your job to understand and comply with contracts you agree to.

Comment: @dan grossman - but the contract is a bit difficult to read... for example it states that charity apps are not allowed, yet there are plenty etc... I think it's a valid worry working with apple.

Comment: @Magnus - charity apps not allowed?....are you sure.....see below the answer for more...and please correct me if i am wrong....

Comment: see for example http://gizmodo.com/5703765/why-does-apple-make-being-a-charitable-app-so-hard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can integrate paypal with any of your application.